# How to POST with Postman to an API in Java?

Tags: java, api, postman

I tried to create a small API to do tests, my Java code seems OK, with Postman when I want to do a GET my list of products is fine for me, on the other hand when I want to do a POST, I have a 400 Bad Request.

Here is my code:

```
// Produits
    @GetMapping(value = "/Produits")
    public List<Product> listeProduits() {
        return productDao.findAll();
    }

    // Récupère un produit par son ID
    @GetMapping(value = "/Produits/{id}")
    public Product afficherUnProduit(@PathVariable int id) {
        return productDao.findById (id);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "Produits/")
    public void ajouterProduit(@RequestBody @Validated Product product, final HttpServletRequest request, Error filterError) {
        productDao.save(product);
    }
```

In Postman, in my body I have the content-type: application / json of filled in.

Where can this problem come from?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I looked at you project. Everything is working ok.
But you have "bad" POST url - "/Produits/"  <--- last slash can be reason for the long not-understanding and "Why this is not working!!". Because in Postman you also must call url -> "localhost:8080/Produits/" <-- here also need last slash.

I've started your project and it works well with this setting of Postman (picrures below). Please look carefully, every symbol is might be a reason.

[image: HEADERS]

[image]

After POST and save I was able to get entity through GET method

[image]

Comment: glad to help if it helped )

Comment: I'm sorry i can't vote for your answer : "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

But thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce getting 400 bad request, but I failed.

Based on your code, I can access to (you might try this)

```
localhost:8080/Produits/
```

but

```
localhost:8080/Produits
```

returned 404 not found.

Maybe you can add more information, which might be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: A screen from Postman : https://imgur.com/2LCOcTV.png

Comment: Sorry, I  still can't reproduce the error. What is the log saying? Maybe you can also send the full class

Answer (score 0):

400 is Bad request. Maybe you do wrong POST request instead GET. Because only "ajouterProduit" method has validation.

Also yeah check your url- if you have "Produits/" set the same in Postman
http://localhost:8080/Produits/

And you can check you service through curl if you has Linux or Mac:
curl http://localhost:8080/Produits/
It will help you understand - you doing wrong Postman request or service has some different url or something

Comment: Yeah. You're doing POST request, ok.
Now check that URL is the same --- slash is matter
And please attach Product class - you have some validation annotations inside and your request not valid for them

Comment: i just post the Product Class : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63285632/13454061

Comment: Very strange. You dont have  any validations.
Please remove. "final HttpServletRequest request, Error filterError" from method signature. But it's just a guess.
Also if you have github link share with me - I will try to help but I think I need to see all project

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help.
GitHub : https://github.com/Nico-GS/Test-Spring-Microservices

Answer (score 0):

And more code :

```
@Override
    public List<Product> findAll () {
        return products;
    }

    @Override
    public Product findById (int id) {
        for (Product product : products) {
            if (product.getId () == id) {
                return product;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public Product save (Product product) {
        products.add(product);
        return product;
    }
```

And Postman screen :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Product Class :

```
public class Product {

    private int id;
    private String nom;
    private int prix;
    private int dureeDeVie;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product (int id, String nom, int prix, int dureeDeVie) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prix = prix;
        this.dureeDeVie = dureeDeVie;
    }

    public int getId () {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNom () {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom (String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public int getPrix () {
        return prix;
    }

    public void setPrix (int prix) {
        this.prix = prix;
    }

    public int getDureeDeVie () {
        return dureeDeVie;
    }

    public void setDureeDeVie (int dureeDeVie) {
        this.dureeDeVie = dureeDeVie;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "Product{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", nom='" + nom + '\'' +
                ", prix=" + prix +
                ", dureeDeVie=" + dureeDeVie +
                '}';
    }

}
```